# COMPILATION ERROR using MAVEN INSTALL

Tags: java, maven

I added a project A into the build path of another project B so that I could use some of the Objects present in project A. I compiled Project B using `Clean Build` in Eclipse but while running `maven install` I get `COMPILATION ERROR'.In some of the answers I found that Maven doesn't know about the build path if this is the case then how can I get rid of this issue. It complaints for the Class which is in project A and I am using it in Project B.

```
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] /C:/ClearCase/ssadat_ESign1_Dev01/MercGlobal/ESign1/ESignature/src/com/mercuryinsurance/esignature/integration/dao/uiintegration/IUiIntegrationDao.java:[7,63] package com.mercuryinsurance.esignature.integration.interceptor does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/ClearCase/ssadat_ESign1_Dev01/MercGlobal/ESign1/ESignature/src/com/mercuryinsurance/esignature/integration/dao/uiintegration/IUiIntegrationDao.java:[33,59] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class ESignatureIntegrationConfig
  location: interface   com.mercuryinsurance.esignature.integration.dao.uiintegration.IUiIntegrationDao
[ERROR] /C:/ClearCase/ssadat_ESign1_Dev01/MercGlobal/ESign1/ESignature/src/com/mercuryinsurance/esignature/integration/manager/uiintegration/IUiIntegrationManager.java:[12,63] package com.mercuryinsurance.esignature.integration.interceptor does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/ClearCase/ssadat_ESign1_Dev01/MercGlobal/ESign1/ESignature/src/com/mercuryinsurance/esignature/integration/manager/uiintegration/IUiIntegrationManager.java:[44,61] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class ESignatureIntegrationConfig
  location: interface com.mercuryinsurance.esignature.integration.manager.uiintegration.IUiIntegrationManager
[ERROR] /C:/ClearCase/ssadat_ESign1_Dev01/MercGlobal/ESign1/ESignature/src/com/mercuryinsurance/esignature/integration/manager/uiintegration/UiIntegrationManager.java:[41,63] package com.mercuryinsurance.esignature.integration.interceptor does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/ClearCase/ssadat_ESign1_Dev01/MercGlobal/ESign1/ESignature/src/com/mercuryinsurance/esignature/integration/manager/uiintegration/UiIntegrationManager.java:[220,68] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class ESignatureIntegrationConfig
  location: class  com.mercuryinsurance.esignature.integration.manager.uiintegration.UiIntegrationManager
[ERROR]  /C:/ClearCase/ssadat_ESign1_Dev01/MercGlobal/ESign1/ESignature/src/com/mercuryin surance/esignature/integration/dao/uiintegration/UiIntegrationDao.java:[15,63]  package com.mercuryinsurance.esignature.integration.interceptor does not exist
[ERROR]   /C:/ClearCase/ssadat_ESign1_Dev01/MercGlobal/ESign1/ESignature/src/com/mercuryin surance/esignature/integration/dao/uiintegration/UiIntegrationDao.java:[86,72]  cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class ESignatureIntegrationConfig
  location: class   com.mercuryinsurance.esignature.integration.dao.uiintegration.UiIntegrationDao
```

Comment: I believe you mean classpath, not build path

Comment: Please provide more details about your Maven project structure (module & dependencies)

Comment: Well, I added it in the Build path by right clicking on the project Build Path --> Configure Build Path.

Comment: What does your pom.xml look like?  Are all the dependencies added (and installed)?

Comment: @Mikael. So far I've just added A into the Build Path of Project B as showed above.

Comment: @puhlen. Do yu mean I need to add Project A as a dependency to the POM?

Comment: @Jaykumar yes, otherwise maven will not know to include it.  Make sure you also install Project A to your local repository (using mvn install)